# how can i use sqlite with android mobile?

Tags: android

i create sqlite database and it works fine with emulator bur when i try this application on my android mobile it give my exception sqliteException no such table 
anyone tell me why and how can i solve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Please give us more details about your exception, like a stack trace and the concerned piece of code.

Comment: what you want to do?please clarify...

Answer (score 0):

**What it could be**

You certainly created the database on the emulator once and use it as of now. But on the real phone you have forgotten to launch the program to create the database once and try to access it anyway.

**General advice**

Try to follow good practice while developing with SQLite for example by using an ORM such as [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) and the model generation in [YML](https://github.com/charignon/OrmLiteYMLSupport) and things will become easier.